# Cannot find tk.h despite having the dev packages installed

Tags: python, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to install [wck](http://effbot.org/zone/wck.htm). But I ran into the following error when running setup.py :

```
fatal error : tk.h : no such file or directory
```

But I already have all the -dev packages installed! I went on and installed tk-dev, tk8.5-dev and tk8.4-dev and the problem persists. I did a 'locate tk.h' and there was no tk.h anywhere in my system. Wherever this problem was reported, people were trying to get tcl.h too. So I did a sudo apt-get install tcl-dev and did a 'locate tcl.h'. Nothing! Where did all the header files go?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that WCKs `setup.py` and `setuplib.py` don't have a clue where to look with the layout on your system, so you will have to fix those to get it working.

I assume your using some variant of Debian Linux there, so maybe have a look at their guidelines for packaging Tcl/Tk.

Basically they recommend adding configure switches like:

```
    --with-tcl=/usr/lib/tclX.Y
    --with-tk=/usr/lib/tkX.Y
    --with-tclincludes=/usr/include/tclX.Y
```

http://pkg-tcltk.alioth.debian.org/tcltk-policy.html/ap-debian_oddities.html

http://pkg-tcltk.alioth.debian.org/tcltk-policy.html/ch-tcltk.html

With that info, you might be able to get it to work by editing `setup.py` and simply adding a version of `find_tk()` that works for your system.

Comment: I could do that but there is no tk.h in my system! Yes, I installed the dev packages.

Comment: Are you sure there is no tk.h? `locate` needs a run of `updatedb` to find anything, so don't trust its output if you didn't run `updatedb` first. Try `find` or simply have a look at the directories i mentioned (/usr/include/tk8.5 for example).

Comment: You were right. tk.h is there at /usr/include/tk. Thanks a lot. I did not know that bit about updatedb